# Please could someone explain the correct way to solve this integral

Tags: integration

given the integral $y=\int_{-1}^b\tfrac{1}{1-x^2}[\tfrac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(x^2-1)^n]dx$

I want to know the correct way to solve it.

My attempt:

I tried integration by parts

$y=uv-\int vdu$

$y=\tfrac{1}{1-x^2}\tfrac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(x^2-1)^n-\int\tfrac{2x}{(1-u^2)^2}\tfrac{d^{n-2}}{du^{n-2}}dx$

But it seems this just leads to a series of n integration by parts

I also tried substitution but it ddnt seem to be working out either

any suggestions?

Note: this is a tiny bit of a much larger question i'm working on

Comment: The original integral is $\displaystyle\int u\,\mathrm dv$, but you seem to have taken the expression with the $(n-1)$-th derivative to be $v$ instead of $\mathrm dv$.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do (didn't put much thoughts in it) :

1. Expand $\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(x^2-1)^n=\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(x-1)^n(x+1)^n$ with Leibniz formula :
   $$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(x^2-1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}(x-1)^{n-k}\frac{n!}{(k+1)!}(x-1)^{k+1}$$
2. Factor $(x^2-1)$ in this expression, to simplify the denominator.
3. Compute $\int_{-1}^b (x-1)^\alpha(x+1)^\beta dx$ for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ integers (is it really $b$, or $1$ ?).
4. Combine results, and hope for the best...